# Как вернуть баллы репутации потерянные при удалении вопроса с моим ответом?

Tags: поддержка, репутация

Я по неизвестной причине потерял 30 баллов репутации. После некоторых исследований я нашел что @ДухСообщества удалил вопрос с моим ответом на котором было 3 голоса "за". Не знаю что делать.

**Вопрос: как мне вернуть 30 баллов репутации?**

PS: Для меня 30 баллов репутации, довольно приличная сумма.

Comment: Теперь вы будете знать, что не нужно писать ответы на вопросы, которые нарушают правила сайта 

Comment: @andreymal нарушают или нет (и будет вопрос удален или нет) штука не объективная, знать заранее наверняка сложно (придет модератор, объявит дубликатом и удалит потом, например). Скорее можно знать то, что всегда есть риск потерять набранное (или не потерять - как повезет) и это нормально.

Comment: @andreymal, ничего он не нарушает.

Comment: @Qwertiy нарушает, в нём два вопроса, он слишком общий

Comment: @andreymal, нет в нём двух вопросов.

Comment: @Qwertiy есть: 1) «проблема в читке построчно»; 2) «разделение слов»

Comment: @Qwertiy ну и ещё «как добавлять элементы в список» может потянуть на третий вопрос, но если автор утверждает «Я знаю», то наверно можно на это не обращать внимания. Но остальные два вопроса всё ещё целых два

Answer (score 8):

Обычно такие вопросы не попадают под автоудаление.

В данном случае вопрос был удалён из-за удаления пользователя, который его задал.

Я восстановил вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Отвечая на прямой вопрос - никак. Эти 30 баллов, почти наверняка, сгорели безвозвратно (механизм восстановления удаленных вопросов существует, но используется крайне редко). Вы можете заработать новые 30 баллов, взамен потерянных, задавая хорошие вопросы, давая хорошие ответы и делая правки - всё как обычно в общем.

---

В общем случае, чем ниже качество вопроса и чем он "проще", тем больше вероятность, что он будет удален вместе с ответами на него, что и приведет к потере набранной на нем репутации.

Comment: Рабочий механизм: кто-то с высоким уровнем репутации видит удаленные вопрос, голосует за восстановление, кидает ссылку в чат с просьбой проголосовать за восстановление. Вопрос в итоге могут восстановить, при условии что вопрос действительно стоящий. Прецидент: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=61194890#61194890

Comment: @insolor спасибо, намекну на это в ответе